# Show date index on x-axis after having to .reset_index() due to the need to use integer index to compute for plotting

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, time-series

Due to computational complexities I had to use integer index to plot multiple values on 3 axes after .reset_index() on a time series DataFrame:

```
plotSet = dataSet.reset_index(drop=True)
```

To plot the candlestick chart, candlestick2_ohlc was used to work with the integer index:

```
from mpl_finance import candlestick2_ohlc
candlestick2_ohlc(ax1, plotSet.open, plotSet.high, plotSet.low, plotSet.close, colorup='g', colordown='r')
```

All 3 axes share the same x-axis though only the bottom ax3 is displayed:

```
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.0, 0.2, 1.0, 0.2], sharex=ax1)
ax3 = fig.add_axes([0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.2], sharex=ax1)
```

Having now plotted all the computed values (iterated over the integer index) on the shared x-axis, how do I replace the integer index to show a date index eg. in %Y-%m-%d format on gridlines [0, 10, .. 60, 70]?

[image]

Reference plotSet data:

```
         date       close        vwap    vector
0  2019-07-31  229.619995  229.307489  0.454934
1  2019-08-01  228.899994  229.912447  0.441829
2  2019-08-02  232.029999  230.501370  0.374164
..        ...         ...         ...       ...
75 2019-11-13  266.910004  268.070642  0.707007
76 2019-11-14  269.670013  268.694046  0.620086
77 2019-11-15  274.739990  270.131488  0.637069
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I'd share how I managed to replace x-axis index with dates..

```
# Initialise index list & date list
ix = []
id = []

# Assign index & dates in reverse order.. in steps of -5 for weekly periods
for i in range(len(plotSet.index)-1, 0, -5):
    ix.append(i)
    id.append(str(plotSet.date.iloc[i]).split()[0][2:])

# Set ticks to index & tick labels to date texts
ax1.set_xticks(ix)
ax1.set_xticklabels(id)
```

Plot for reference.. ax3 displays date labels shared with ax1 set prior:
[image]